# SVN pre-commit hook to validate subdirectory name only in shell script

Tags: svn, pre-commit-hook, pre-commit

I am trying to o add a pre-commit hook that validate sub-directory name in yyyymmdd format.It should be applicable to specific directories only not to whole project folder.Please help to write the hook script.

Answer (score 1):

It is an easy job. You should rename the pre-commit.tmpl file located in hook directory under your repository into pre-commit (Linux) or pre-commit.bat/exe (for windows). the commit path and other info are passed to your hook script through command line parameters. Take a look at [this guide](http://cri.ensmp.fr/~coelho/svn-pre-commit.html). You may also take a look at [this link](http://wordaligned.org/articles/a-subversion-pre-commit-hook) and [this one](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.php.php-codesniffer.svn-pre-commit.php) for more info.